# SharePoint Framework: how to display document library data in a SPFx client side web part using ReactJs and Type Script

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, react

I need to fetch data from document library which resides in SharePoint online and display in spfx client web part with filtering, paging and sorting features.

**Tools:**
ReactJs,
TypeScript,
Visual Studio code,
gulp

Any demo samples or references would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do a Google search for "SharePoint Framework Tutorial". You'll find a whole bunch.  Try a couple of those, and if you get stuck on something come back here and ask a more specific question. If you've already tried some, tell us what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: I retrieved list data from SharePoint online and displayed in a SPFx webpart . But How can I do the same with Document library? And If I select any item it should display Check-in/Check-Out option. If I check-out, the doc must become read-only to other users. Please suggest.

Comment: Getting documets (items) from Document library is the same as getting items from list. There is one difference, ``Title`` of a document is ``FileLeafRef`` field. To find if the document is Checked Out use ``CheckoutUser`` field, that will tell you the user who checked out the document.

Comment: I didn't get your point Lukas, can you explain please? Only list items could be displayed in my spfx web part but not library files

Answer (score 1):

You can use the get method to get the all the fields values from the Document library.

**Code:**

```
@autobind
private GetListItems(): void {       
    this.props.spHttpClient.get(`${this.props.siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${this.props.listName}')/items?$select=fieldNames`,
        SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
        {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
                'odata-version': ''
            }
        })
        .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IListItem[] }> => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((response: { value: IListItem[] }): void => {
            //Write your logic to form the json object from response
        }, (error: any): void => {
            this.setState({
                status: 'Loading all items failed with error: ' + error,                 
            });
        });
}
```

Once you formed the json object, you can use the **"material-ui-datatables"** to achieve the sorting, filtering and paging functionality. You have to just pass the JSON object to this component.

**Please find the reference below**

[material-ui-datatables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-datatables)

Answer (score 1):

```
pnp.sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/dev/Shared Documents/test").getItem().then(item => {

    console.log(item);
});

pnp.sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/dev/Shared Documents/test").getItem("Title", "Modified").then(item => {

    console.log(item);
});

pnp.sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/dev/Shared Documents/test").getItem().then(item => {

    // you can also chain directly off this item instance
    item.getCurrentUserEffectivePermissions().then(perms => {

        console.log(perms);
    });
});
```

**References:**

- https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core
- https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Files

Comment: Hi Goshky, I like this approach suggested by you. As I'm beginner in SPFx, how can I read document library and do check-out/check-in in the spfx webpart. Any suggestions? I don't know where to start.

Comment: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Files#check-in

Comment: Look at the link above.

Comment: Thanks, any idea on how to display doc icons and check in, check out status. I am using reactjs and typescript