# How to render Document Library from custom web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern

So I have a handful of Document Libraries on a SharePoint online modern page.
I currently render them with the Document Library Web Part that is provided out of the box by SharePoint.

Now the customers requirement is to dynamically show/hide those Web Parts dynamically based on entries in some other List.

I assumed the most robust solution would be to create a custom Web Part to render to fetch the List and render the document libraries with SPFx, but I can't for the Live of me find out anything about the out-of-the-box Document Library web part.

No documentation, no source code, what library it is using, nothing. And rebuilding it from scratch just cant be the correct answer, why rebuild something that's already there.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if the answers in this thread are helpful to you.

[SharePoint Framework: how to display document library data in a SPFx client side web part using ReactJs and Type Script](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/236502/sharepoint-framework-how-to-display-document-library-data-in-a-spfx-client-side)